# Método se ejecuta dos veces

Tags: html, c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente problema, el método "I_pageobject" se ejecuta dos veces, no entiendo el porque de este problema espero me puedan apoyar, el programa corre correctamente, pero al llegar al metodo este termina y se vuelve a ejecutar nuevamente, después de la segunda ejecución me permite ver la informacion que estoy mandando a llamar.

"using ZXing" es una librería para poder leer el código QR, lo que pretendo con esto es traer la información de una pagina WEB.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZXing;


namespace QR_Clientes
{
    public partial class OpenFileTxt : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog File = new OpenFileDialog();
        BarcodeReader br = new BarcodeReader();
        WebBrowser nav = new WebBrowser();
        public OpenFileTxt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            File.Filter = "JPG |*.jpg|PNG|*.png"; 
        }
        private void OpenBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(File.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileOpTxt.Text = File.FileName;
                ImgFile.Image = Image.FromFile(File.FileName);
                string texto = br.Decode((Bitmap)ImgFile.Image).ToString();
                QrdataTxt.Text = texto;
            }  
        }        
        private void Consultabtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            nav.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            nav.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.I_pageobject);
            nav.Navigate(QrdataTxt.Text);
        }
        public void I_pageobject (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection doc = this.nav.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");
            HtmlElement s = nav.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            HtmlElement f = nav.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")[4];
            RsocialTxt.Text = s.InnerText + " " + f.InnerText;
            HtmlElement g = nav.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")[10];
            EstatusTxt.Text = g.InnerText;
        }        

        private void ImgFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        private void OpenFileTxt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando ejecutas el click te suscribis al evento y ahi entraria la primera vez, y cuando termina de cargar la pagina estaria entrando la segunda vez, segun creo entender. Tenes alguna forma de colocar un operador await en los metodos que traen la info?

Comment: No lo había pensado así,  intentare colocar un operador Async / Await. haber que tal me va.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque te suscribes al evento cada vez que se ejecuta `OpenBtn_Click` y si es lo que su nombre indica, agregarás una suscripción y en consecuencia una ejecución cada vez que le des click al botón asociado.

La sugerencia, en este caso, es que hagas la suscripción al evento `DocumentCompleted` en el constructor del formulario y quitarla del lugar donde la tienes actualmente.

El siguiente ejemplo omite parte del código para mantener el foco en lo importante:

```
public partial class OpenFileTxt : Form
{
    //...

    WebBrowser nav = new WebBrowser();

    public OpenFileTxt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        File.Filter = "JPG |*.jpg|PNG|*.png";

        //La suscripción al evento
        nav.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.I_pageobject);

    }

    private void Consultabtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        nav.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        //Quita la suscripción de aquí...

        nav.Navigate(QrdataTxt.Text);
    }
   
     //...
}
```

Comment: Hace unos días, intente lo mismo que tu me estas sugiriendo y conseguí que no ingresara dos veces al método para ejecutarlo. Muchas gracias.